# Why does the screen stay the same color after pushing the button?

Tags: python, pygame

`import pygame`

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption('Checkers')
```

```
while True:
  screen.fill((114,157,224))
  pygame.display.update()
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
  elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
      screen.fill((70,44,133))
      pygame.display.update()
```

I tried to change `pygame.KEYDOWN` to `pygame.key.get_pressed()`  but nothing changed.

Comment: move `screen.fill((114,157,224))` outside of the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the display in every frame, but you have to change the [`Color`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) used  to [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) the display when the button is pressed:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fillColor = pygame.Color(114,157,224)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                fillColor = pygame.Color(70,44,133)
  
    screen.fill(fillColor)

    # draw scene
    # [...]
  
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)